# Changing font for four buttons at once in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Goal**

I have created 4 buttons that are in the default font in Tkinter. Now I decided that all the four buttons are too small. So I want to increase the size of the font in them.

**Problem faced**

I don't want to add the thing `font=custom` where `custom=tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size='18')` in all the four statements.

Is there a way to do this for the whole frame that these buttons are there in?

**code**

```
f = self.frame
custom = Font(family='Helvetica',size=15)

start = Button(f,text='START',command=self.startrunning)


start.pack(side="top")


stop =Button(f,text='STOP',command=self.stoprunning)
stop.pack(side="top")

lap = Button(f,text='LAP',command=self.endlap)
lap.pack(side='top')

reset = Button(f,text="RESET",command = self.reset)
reset.pack(side="top")

close = Button(f,text="QUIT",bg="black",fg = "red",command=self.quitwin)
close.pack(side="top")
```

**Please** help me with some shortcut to achieve the goal. And if there is no shortcut please tell me that too!

Comment: you could just make a list called `buttons`, that would be clearer

Comment: sir. would that help me change the font of all the buttons at one go?

Comment: with a `for` loop, yes

Comment: Why is using `font=custom` not acceptable? That's actually the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttons = [stop, lap, reset, close]
my_font = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size='18')
for button in buttons:
    button.config(font=my_font)
```

Comment: sir: I added the above code and it worked. But I added it after packing the buttons. Then how come it changed the font??

Comment: @IcyFlame `config` triggers the refresh I believe. Also there is no need to call me sir!

Comment: Well, I checked your profile there was no age so to be on the safer side I addressed you as Sir!!!'

Comment: This creates a unique font for each widget. It would be better to create the instance of `Font` outside the loop. Not that having multiple fonts is that big of a deal, but one should still practice good code hygiene every chance you get.

Comment: @IcyFlame: it worked after packing because that's how it's designed to work. This is what Tk calls a "named font" (even though you didn't give it a name...). They are remarkably powerful. If, for example, at runtime you decided to change the size of the buttons you don't have to re-run the `config` method on every button.  Instead, you use `config` on the font, and any widget that uses that font will instantly reflect the change.